# Take turns using semaphores

Tags: unix, process, semaphore

This might be a trivial problem but I couldn't find any clear answer. How can you make two processes take turns using only semaphores? I don't want to use sleep or other IPCs. The result should be something like:

```
Process 1 did something
Process 2 did something
Process 1 did something
Process 2 did something
Process 1 did something
Process 2 did something
Process 1 did something
Process 2 did something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two semaphores, one for each process, lets say S1 and S2. The sequence of interaction between processes P1 and P2 would be as follows:

1. P1 waits on S1, P2 waits on S2.
2. Lets say that initially S1 is open, S2 closed.
3. P1 does its work - closes S1, opens S2, and waits on S1
4. P2 does its work - closes S2, opens S1, and waits on S2
5. start over from 3.